# Déchets vs poubelle

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Sometimes I see garbage cans labelled as “poubelle” and other times I see them labelled “déchets”.

I realize both are correct but I'm interested in the subtle differences between the two. Is “déchets” more in reference to garbage itself and “poubelle” specifically a garbage bin?

*P.S. I live in Quebec but looking for a general answer.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

déchets = contenu = garbage

= ordures

poubelle = contenant = garbage bin

Ce mot vient du préfet de Paris [Eugène Poubelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eug%C3%A8ne_Poubelle), qui fit installer ces "poubelles" en 1884.

Comment: Ah bon? Vous apprenez quelque chose de nouveau chaque jour!

Answer (score 4):

Comme l’ont mentionné Guillaume & Frank, le *déchet* est le contenu, la *poubelle* est le contenant. On peut cependant ajouter que le déchet ne va pas forcément à la poubelle, puisque le terme peut aussi bien désigner la partie d’une matière qui n’est pas utilisée pendant sa transformation. Ainsi, les petits morceaux de bois créés par le découpage d’une pièce plus grande peuvent n’avoir aucune utilité immédiate pour le projet en cours, auquel cas elles sont désignées comme déchet, mais peuvent être conservées pour usage ultérieur plutôt que jetées. Les restants de nourriture compostés sont un autre exemple de déchets qui ne finissent pas à la poubelle.

Il est commun autant dans les usages littéraires que journalistiques ou quotidiens d’assimiler le tout et la partie. Par ce processus d’assimilation, appelé *synecdoque*, le journaliste qui parle de *Washington* indiquera le pouvoir politique américain, le romancier qui parlera des *mortels* désignera les membres de l’espèce humaine et le client d’un restaurant qui se plaindra d’une assiette trop petite a vraisemblablement en tête le peu de contenu de celle-ci – *on disait communément* assiétée *dans ma jeunesse, ce terme semble plus rare aujourd’hui* – plutôt que la petitesse de l’objet.

Par synecdoque, donc, on désigne souvent les déchets comme poubelle, ou les poubelles comme déchets. En faisant allusion à la *cueillete des ordures* (expression généralement utilisée au Québec par les entités municipales, peut-être aussi ailleurs dans la Francophonie), on entendra souvent et sans distinction particulière qu’on *ramasse les déchets* ou qu’on *ramasse les poubelles*. Le premier est très exact quant à la description de l’opération, alors que le second fait allusion au ramassage DU CONTENU des poubelles.

Quant aux indications auxquelles vous faites référence sur les contenants, il n’y a en pratique pas de différence, mais on approche les usagers possibles de l’objet de deux manières différentes, les informant de la nature de l’objet lorsque l’on y écrit *POUBELLE*, ou des possibilités qu’il offre de disposer de ses déchets lorsque l’on y mentionne *DÉCHETS*. La différence est mineure, aussi mineure que celle existant entre deux panneaux indiquant *« Commencez ici »* et *« Début du parcours »* pour aider les gens à parcourir une exposition dans un musée.

---

Petit ajout d’un autre exemple, multi-linguistique celui-ci, de deux approches différentes aboutissant au même résultat (ce genre de panneau de circulation a longtemps été courant au Québec):

[image: Ce genre de panneau de circulation a longtemps été courant au Québec]

En français, on nomme la manœuvre à effectuer en ce point; en anglais, la directive est plus ambiguë et peut s’interpréter diversement: on pourrait, en plus d’une interprétation identique à celle du français *Arrêt* (voir les commentaires de Luke ci-dessous), y voir plutôt un impératif: on ordonne aux conducteurs de s’arrêter.

Comment: Although I think the notion of transposition in translation is important, I want to point out that "stop" could be the same as "arrêt" grammatically. :) But I wonder if [this sign](https://unfamiliarplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/dechets.jpg) I spotted on a ship in Ontario is so awkward because of an attempt to render "Interdiction de ..." in English!

Comment: I take note. Hearing people mention _arrêts_ in English, I sort of remember always hearing _stop signs_, as if the simple mention of a stop wasn't enough, though I also heard _come to a complete stop_. I also had the command buttons in mind, how they use imperative in English (Add Comment, Go, Look It Up, etc.), while they use infinitive in French (Ajouter un commentaire, Rechercher, Démarrer, ...). Should I remove the Stop sign part, then?

Comment: Just like your good example of the blurring of the container & its contents w/the verb “remasser,” I think some blurring can also be attributed, at least in English, to using prepositions in arguably imprecise ways (“Put that **in** the trash”//”Put that **with** the trash.” Similarly, brides-to-be [used to] put items **in**  their trousseaux, which expanded (if not questionable) use of “in” instead of “with” encouraged the extension of the notion of “trousseau” to mean, to some, not only the contents of a “hope chest,” but also the chest itself: “The whole kit & caboodle,” if you will! +1

Comment: @Feelew If you want to edit the stop sign part you could mention that it's at least ambiguous, whereas the French isn't. English signs definitely come in a variety of syntactic structures ("yield" is clearly an imperative, but "bridge ices" appears to be an elliptical declarative sentence...), but I often say "There's a stop there" referring to the stop sign.

Comment: Another good example of an English/French signage difference is this one I just spotted in Les Choristes: on the wall of the school a sign says "Interdiction de courir", whereas it's hard to imagine the English being anything but "No running" (or perhaps the overly eloquent "Running is not permitted")...

Comment: I think the stop sign is a good and relevant example of a container (a sign containing a message) being so closely related to its contents (the message itself, regardless of how stated, if at all) that a blurring of the two things can occur.  The fact that some people refer to “traffic lights/signals” as “stop/red lights” might also be relevant here in that a red light is one of the options/messages “contained” in/presented by a traffic signal.

Comment: Papa Poule, On the subject of prepositions used in slightly modified ways, on the French side we could mention ‘sur’ (pronounced ‘su’), replacing ‘chez’ in Quebec: _aller su les parents_; or replacing ‘à’ in Switzerland, where it’s been common for a long time, and in France, where it is quickly gaining popularity: _(se rendre sur Paris)_.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking mainly about how using “dans” with “les déchets” (mettre **dans** les déchets) instead of “avec” could contribute to (or maybe arise from?) the synecdochic notion that “les déchets” (at least in the plural) also includes the container holding it (and **into** which more of it can be added) (just as “putting it **in** the trash” implies either “putting it in the trash [**can/container**] or “putting it in the [**pile of**] trash” in English). Anyway, French is fortunate to have “**a**ux,” which works well in both “aux déchets” and “à la/aux poubelle/s.”

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *déchets* (or *détritus*) are what you put in in the *poubelle*.